# Am I forced to create my own Error type?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I want to write a `get_members` function that returns members from a GitHub team.

```
pub fn get_members(group_id: &str) -> Result<Vec<User>, Error> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let query = format!("https://api.github.com/teams/{}/members?access_token={}",
                    group_id,
                    config::get_env(config::ENV_TOKEN));

    println!("{}", query);

    let mut res = try!(client
                    .get(&query)
                    .header(UserAgent("my/app".to_owned()))
                    .send());

    let mut body = String::new();
    try!(res.read_to_string(&mut body));
    try!(json::decode(&body));
}
```

There are two different types of errors into play. One is `hyper::error::Error` and the other is `rustc_serialize::json::DecoderError`.

I thought I could just use implement `From<::hyper::error::Error> for Error` and `From<rustc_serialize::json::DecoderError>`. But since neither `io::Error` nor one of the other two errors is in my crate I'm not allowed to follow that approach.

I wonder what's the way to go here. Do I need to come up with my own `AppError` Type and then implement the `From<>` trait for that? Is that the way to go?

Comment: First of all, make sure you've read [Error Handling in Rust](http://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling).

Comment: That article is simply brilliant and should go straight into the official book!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually yes, using your own error type is the way to go. There are even several crates (of which I was able to find only [this](https://crates.io/crates/wrapped_enum) one now) which help you to remove the boilerplate. This approach should also be used when you're writing a library, as opposed to an application.

There is an option, however, of using [`Box<Error>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait object as your error type. Lots of error types in Rust and in third-party libraries implement this trait; therefore, using `Result<..., Box<Error>>` as a return type should work almost always.